# TFS In Android Studio Not Work

Tags: android, tfs, android-studio

I installed Android Studio TFS plug-in From JetBrains web site and after I install it, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to install TFS and if it's not what is the best source control to use as Team work source controller?

Comment: Do you have any details on what is not working? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the JetBrains plugins have not been updated since TFS 2010,and you need to have Team Explorer 2010 installed to use them.

If you install Team Explorer 2010 it should work.

Comment: i use Team Foundation Server 2013

Comment: Then you will also need to install Team Explorer 2010.

Comment: Note that you have it working I recommend sending an angry email to Jetbrains telling them to upgrade their 5 year old code. The 2010 API's drop out of support in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

The TFS does not work, because plugin working only the Ultimate version , like Android Studio is based in JetBrains Free, it not will work.

Comment: The english is hard to understand, could you improve the answer a bit? Especially the 2nd part starting from 'like Android Studio' is not understandable.

Comment: I Changed The IDE. I Use to Eclipse And It Work Fine.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I was not really clear in my explanation. But in short, what I meant was that: because the android studio have been developed on the free IntelliJ platform it has no support for plugins which integrates with TFS. So you can use the TFS would have to get the paid version IntelliJ.